# Linq to SQL multiple Left joins using multiple fields and subquery

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Basically I want to be able to recreate this query in Linq

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers

LEFT JOIN Orders LastOrder
ON LastOrder.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
&& LastOrder.CreatedOn = (Select MAX(CreatedOn) FROM Orders WHERE CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId)

LEFT JOIN OrderStatus
ON OrderStatus.OrderStatusId = LastOrder.OrderStatusId
```

Comment: Are FK relationships set up in the database between customers and orders and orderstatus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
from c in dc.Customers
join o1 in dc.Orders
on
new { o1.CustomerId,
        (from inner
         in dc.Orders
         where inner.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
         select inner.CreatedOn).Max()
    }
equals
new { c.CustomerId,
      o1.CreatedOn
    }
join o2 in dc.Orders
on
o1.OrderStatusId == o2.OrderStatusId
into joined
select joined
```

Comment: Thanks I got this to work with some tweaks - I could not get this version to compile exactly do to scope issues.  This is the equivalent of what I ended up using.

from c in dc.Customers
join o1 in dc.Orders
on
new { c.CustomerId,Createdon=
        (from inner
         in dc.Orders
         where inner.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
         select inner.CreatedOn).Max()
    }
equals
new { o1.CustomerId,
      o1.CreatedOn
    }
into c01
from z in c01.DefaultIfEmpty()
join o2 in dc.Orders
on
z1.OrderStatusId == o2.OrderStatusId
into joined
select joined

Comment: @Jeremy Coenen cool! Glad you got it working. I wrote it in the browser, so sorry for any mistakes.